# javascript multiple if in function

Tags: javascript

i am confuse about use multiple if in one functions 
this code not work

```
function hitung(){
    document.getElementById("judul").innerHTML = "Hasil Perhitungan Biaya";

    if(document.getElementById('merk').value == "vario") {
        document.getElementById("motor").innerHTML = "Merk Motor : Vario";
    };
    if(document.getElementById('merk').value == "Beat") {
        document.getElementById("motor").innerHTML = "Merk Motor : Beat";
    };
    if(document.getElementById('merk').value == "Megapro") {
        document.getElementById("motor").innerHTML = "Merk Motor : Mega Pro";
    }
    if(document.getElementById('merk').value == "supra") {
        document.getElementById("motor").innerHTML = "Merk Motor : Supra X";
    };
}
```

i try use else if but it won't work too,
anybody can help me with this simple question ?

Comment: Please define "won't work". Do you get any error? Different result than expected?

Comment: do you also call the function?

Comment: <a onclick="hitung();" class="button round">Hitung Biaya</a>

Comment: i mean the result not show up, just show the first function, Merk motor : Vario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work fine. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/g21hrd0r/2/). I cleaned up your code a bit too. Your problem may be caused on how you call your function.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="judul"></div>
<input type="text" id="merk" />
<div id="motor"></div>
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function hitung() {
    judul.innerHTML = "Hasil Perhitungan Biaya";

    if (merk.value == "vario") {
        motor.innerHTML = "Merk Motor : Vario";
    };
    if (merk.value == "Beat") {
        motor.innerHTML = "Merk Motor : Beat";
    };
    if (merk.value == "Megapro") {
        motor.innerHTML = "Merk Motor : Mega Pro";
    }
    if (merk.value == "supra") {
        motor.innerHTML = "Merk Motor : Supra X";
    };
}

var judul = document.getElementById("judul");
var merk = document.getElementById('merk');
var motor = document.getElementById("motor");

document.getElementById('start').onclick = hitung;
```

Comment: Np, make sure to mark this as the right answer. Good luck.